# Can a distribution list be expanded as individual contacts in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, distribution-list

Is it possible to expand a distribution list in Outlook 2007 to become individual contacts also? I don't mean for the recipient list of an email, but in the contacts folder.

Comment: I don't know if this will make any difference, but is the contact list local, or a Microsoft Exchange contact list? Are you using Exchange, or stand-alone Outlook? Can you add a screenshot and better describe how you want it to work?

Comment: I don't think Outlook supports this, because individual distribution lists are held as an actual "Contact".  The only way to expand the distribution list is to actually double-click it to view the entries.

Comment: @KCotreau The contact list is local; it's my Contacts folder already. Outlook is connected to Exchange at my organisation.

Comment: @Breakthrough I suspected that might be the case. Outlook isn't exactly forthcoming in letting you access your data - there so many more things I'd like to do with my email.

Comment: @James, what did you need to see the contact list entries for?  Maybe there is an alternative solution to your original problem...

Comment: @Breakthrough I want the individual entries in my contact list so I can send individual emails to them. I just had the distribution sent to me. I guess I'll just have to do it by hand.

Comment: @James I don't know if this is what you want, but if you open a distribution list and double-click on one of the contacts, there is an "Add to Contacts" button in the pop-up window.